# jQuery image rotate need fix

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Atestat - Masini Clasice</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

<script src="js/jqueryrotate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var value = 0
$("#image").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=180;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
     }
}); 
</script>



</head>

<body>

<img src="img/volan.png" id="image"/>

    <footer>

    <h2>Atestat <i>Masini clasice</i></h2>
    <a class="tzine"><i><b>Razvan Radu</b></i></a>

</footer>


</body>
```

The centered image called "volan" should rotate when i click it, but id doesnt work
Im using jQuery Easing v1.3 and jQueryRotate v2.3 and jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1.

Comment: Why not just use CSS `transform` with `transition`?

Comment: you have to wait for the dom to be ready!

Comment: @chipChocolate because i want to add some other effects to that image, like when i click it to rotate  and to appear 2 other button next to it

Comment: You have to wait the DOM to be ready, as @DanielA.White said, and, I think it's "angle" and not "value".

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
  var value = 0
  $("#image").rotate({ 
    bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=180;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No problem dude. Of course, i recommend you to use CSS transitions and transform, and your other "effects" and the other buttons with JS.

Comment: can i ask u if u can show me an example ? i mean this is what im trying to do : http://s23.postimg.org/u2vpdzi6z/Untitled.png and maybe and effect fadein / slide from center to left / right

Comment: right now just simply rotate an image at 180 degrees on click event

Answer (score 0):

The call of the outer rotate funtions is not needed. Just use the click event. Within there you can call your rotate function:

```
var angle = 0;
$("#image").click(function() {
    angle += 180;
    $(this).rotate({ animateTo:angle})
});
```

To be sure that your events will be set properly you have to call it after the DOM has been fully loaded:

```
$(function() {
    var angle = 0;
    $("#image").click(function() {
        angle += 180;
        $(this).rotate({ animateTo:angle})
    });
});
```